# Qual è il senso di "avanzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Mio fratello ora prendeva a una a una le ciliege dal tricorno e le portava alla bocca come fossero canditi. Poi soffiava via i noccioli con uno sbuffo delle labbra, attento che non gli macchiassero il panciotto. 
>          – Questo mangiagelati, – disse uno, – **cosa avanza da noi?** Perché ci viene tra i piedi? Perché non si mangia quelle del suo giardino, di ciliege? – Ma erano un po' intimiditi, perché avevano capito che sugli alberi era più in gamba lui di tutti loro.

La mia domanda è sul significato della frase "cosa avanza da noi?" in questo brano. Tra le differenti accezioni del verbo  "avanzare" non sono sicura a quale corrisponda questo uso. Uno dei significati che ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2) (con l'indicazione di "antico") è quello di "risparmiare". Quindi, la frase significa "cosa risparmia per noi?" nel senso che il fratello dell'io narrante (cioè, Cosimo, il protagonista del romanzo) sta mangiando tutte le ciliege e non lascerà nessuna per gli altri ragazzi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Avanzo qualcosa da Charo* significa che Charo ha un debito verso di me. È il significato 2 in http://treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2/

Può essere adoperato in senso lato, in questo caso nel senso di *gli dobbiamo forse qualcosa?*, cioè *abbiamo forse un debito verso di lui?* perché il comportamento del mangiagelati ricorda un creditore che sta alle costole del debitore e coglie ogni occasione per recuperare una parte del credito, in questo caso le ciliegie (o come scrive Calvino, le ciliege).

Answer (score 0):

Avanza in questo caso ha il significato di:

> Questo mangiagelati, – disse uno, – cosa **vuole** da noi?

oppure anche

> Questo mangiagelati, – disse uno, – cosa **pretende** da noi?

Il personaggio si chiede quindi che cosa volesse da loro, si chiedeva se per caso fossero debitori di qualcosa nei suoi confronti.

Comment: forse nel senso di _"che pretese avanza nei nostri confronti?"_

Comment: Esattamente come dici tu

Comment: Cioè l'accezione 2 della voce del Treccani citata da Charo?

Comment: @DaG Esatto, dover avere, essere creditore di qualche cosa

Comment: O forse la 4.c di [questa voce del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare1/)?

Comment: @Charo No, a me sembra più appropriato dover avere, volere, pretendere

Comment: Forse il mio problema è che non capisco bene questa accezione 2 della voce del Treccani che ho citato nella domanda.

Comment: Sarebbe così se ci fosse stato scritto "cosa avanza **per** noi "

Comment: Per "così" vuoi dire quello che ho scritto nella domanda?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75902/discussion-between-abarisone-and-charo).