# Che cosa significa "avanzare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Non c’era nessuno delle parti del Pavaglione che potessi dirmelo amico, ma non avevo neanche dei nemici, salvo forse un balordo che senza **avanzar** niente da me e soltanto per far lo spiritoso m’aveva attaccato una festa a Manera, ma m’abbrivò solo a parole.

Non capisco bene il significato dell'espressione "senza avanzar niente da me" in questo testo. Mi chiedo se, tra le [accezioni che ho trovato nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare1), quella adatta al contesto della frase sarebbe questa:

> **b.** fig. Osare, prendere ardire a fare una cosa: *s’avanzava a domande, che facevano stupire* (Manzoni).

Oppure il significato è lo stesso di quello spiegato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9315), che corrisponde a questa altra [accezione del Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2/)?

> **2.** tr. Dover avere, essere creditore di qualche cosa: *avanzo da lui parecchie centinaia di euro; avanzi nulla da me?*

Comment: Avanzare in questo caso vuol dire pretendere, richiedere qualcosa come se fosse dovuto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qual è il senso di "avanzare" in questo contesto?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/qual-%c3%a8-il-senso-di-avanzare-in-questo-contesto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il significato di "avanzare" in questo brano è lo stesso di quello spiegato in [quest'altra risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9315) e corrisponde a questa [definizione del vocabolario Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2/):

> **2.** tr. Dover avere, essere creditore di qualche cosa: *avanzo da lui parecchie centinaia di euro; avanzi nulla da me?*

Che la persona qualificata come "balordo" non avanzasse niente dall'io narrante vuol dire che quest'ultimo non aveva nessun debito, non doveva niente a questo "balordo". Quindi, quando questo "balordo" "aveva attaccato una festa" all'io narrante non l'aveva fatto perché pretendesse da lui qualcosa che l'era dovuto ma, come spiegato nel testo, l'aveva fatto "soltanto per far lo spiritoso".

Comment: Ho deciso di scrivere io stessa questa risposta perché vedo che cominciano a proliferare domande senza risposta e non credo che questo sia positivo per il sito. Debbo dire, però, che conosco la risposta grazie ai vostri commenti. Quando ho scritto la domanda non lo sapevo. Notate che avevo messo un link alla risposta all'altra domanda.